# If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on [0,1] show $g(x)=\int_{[x,1]} f(t)t^{-1}dt$ is Lebesgue integrable on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Also want to show $\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dx = \int_{[0,1]}f(x)dx$.

So since $f \in \mathcal{L}([0,1]), f=u-v$ where $u$ and $v$ are upper functions. Then I need to show $\int_{(x,1]} u(t)t^{-1}dt$ is an upper function because that will give $g \in \mathcal{L}([0,1])$.

Not really sure how to go about doing this. I have to show this satisfies the properties of being an upper function but that's what I'm having trouble starting.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^1|g(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1 dx\int_x^1 \left|\dfrac{f(t)}{t}\right|dt = \int_0^1 dt \int_0^t  \left|\dfrac{f(t)}{t}\right|dx = \int_0^1 \left|f(t)\right|dt$

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. If I'm mistaken, why/how does this answer the question I asked?

Comment: This **is** a valid answer to the question. The problem probably is that you are using an unusual definition of the integral (please tell us more about your definition, e.g. what is an "upper function"?), or tell us what you do not understand about the solution above (it uses Fubini's theorem, do you know it?).

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that theorem. My teacher is following a set of online notes, where I believe the main idea is to teach Lebesgue Integration without really using measure theory. The integral is defined in this chapter here, along with upper functions and other related things http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnilifolder/ili04.pdf